DNS.GetHosyByName not returning expected results upon .net Migration
Before migrating from net461 -> .net6.0, Dns.GetHosyByName() returned list of aliases but after migration it returns back 0 results. Any reason why this would be the case? Any other way to retrieve list of aliases?
